# What is the best way to align content left and right in a header while using flexbox?

Tags: css, header, alignment, flexbox

I'm struggling to find the right keywords to solve this.

Here is my code that works:

> HTML

```
 <div class="windowTopBar">
   <span style="display: inline-block;"><b>System Properties</b></span>
   <span style="float: right;">[?][X]</span>
 </div>
```

> CSS

```
 .windowTopBar {
   background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000080, #1084D0);
   color: white;
   height: 2em;
   min-height: 2em;
   align-items: center;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

This works and floats the "System Properties" to the left and the "what will be two img buttons" to the right.

If I put the span styles into classes, it stops working. Why?

If I put "display: flex;" into the parent div, it also stops working? Why? I really want to use display flex. I've been messing with this for quite a long time actually.

My favourite solution so far, was to do display: flex and justify-content: flex-end on the parent (while using two child divs instead of spans), but I couldn't figure out how to float the "System Properties" over to the left side.

I am trying to make it responsive, so I would appreciate if someone could help me understand what the bestpractice is and defintely help me understand why span style property works in html but not as a css class.

To be extra clear, if i do:

> HTML

```
 <span class="test1">blah1</span>
 <span class="test1">blah2</span>
```

> CSS

```
 .test1 {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .test2 {
   float: right;
 }
```

It doesnt work. Help please! :) Forgive me if I'm asking too much. This is my first ever question, but I've been lurking for years.

Comment: I just found this, http://www.adam-bray.com/blog/107/simple-css-alignments-flexbox/

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Comment: that was helpful, thanks for posting it. i'm saving it to my secret bin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.windowTopBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
 <div class="windowTopBar">
   <span><b>System Properties</b></span>
   <span>[?][X]</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually just found the same thing myself, doh.

Comment: I was having a hard time on Google because of all the old questions that were using crazy table methods and floating. flex space-between is a gem. I'll add the keyword to my post so someone can hopefully find it one day.